# 502 error when updating website or uploading large files

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, bitnami, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-cdn

Maybe my setup is considered overkill for a single VM but I prefer it this way to have it behind a load balancer.

Whenever any attempts to update large quantity of files or update several plugins at a time, it will produce a 502 error from the browser end. VM is accessible by direct IP.

Is this something to do with the Health check settings or Apache server configuration?

The setup as below:

- Bitnami Wordpress
- Google Cloud Platform
- Google Cloud CDN
- Google Cloud HTTP Load Balancer

Health Check Settings:

```
Path / 

Protocol HTTP 

Port 80 

Proxy protocol NONE 

Logs Disabled 

Interval 30 seconds 

Timeout 30 seconds 

Healthy threshold 3 consecutive successes 

Unhealthy threshold 3 consecutive failures
```

Comment: Find out where bitnami puts the web server error.log. Take a look at the last few tens of lines of that log. You may be able to figure out the error from them. If you still need help, please [edit] your question to show us the last few lines of that log.

Comment: Review the logs for both Apache and PHP. Most likely you have a tiny instance size and the uploads are overwhelming the server and you will find either memory starvation or PHP code is crashing (throwing an exception).